# How can I decode and store the images from this json file?

Tags: php, json

I have a json file which looks like this :

```
[
  {
    "skyGoUrl": "http://go.sky.com/vod/content/GOPCMOVIES/RSS/Movies/content/assetId/6ba3fb6afd03e310VgnVCM1000000b43150a________/videoId/d1bf901693832410VgnVCM1000000b43150a________/content/playSyndicate.do",
    "url": "http://skymovies.sky.com/parental-guidance/review",
    "reviewAuthor": "Tim Evans",
    "id": "8ad589013b496d9f013b4c0b684a4a5d",
    "cert": "U",
    "viewingWindow": {
      "startDate": "2013-12-27",
      "wayToWatch": "Sky Movies",
      "endDate": "2015-01-21"
    },
    "headline": "Parental Guidance",
    "cardImages": [
      {
        "url": "http://vodassets.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/unscaled/2012/11/29/Parental-Guidance-VPA.jpg",
        "h": 1004,
        "w": 768
      },
      {
        "url": "http://vodassets.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/unscaled/2013/07/15/LPA-Parental-guidance.jpg",
        "h": 748,
        "w": 1024
      },
      {
        "url": "http://vodassets.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/unscaled/2012/11/29/Parental-Guidance-VPA-VPA-to-CP3.jpg",
        "h": 460,
        "w": 320
      },
      {
        "url": "http://vodassets.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/unscaled/2012/11/29/Parental-Guidance-VPA-VPA-to-CP4.jpg",
        "h": 920,
        "w": 640
      },
      {
        "url": "http://vodassets.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/unscaled/2013/07/15/LPA-Parental-guidance-LPA-to-LP3.jpg",
        "h": 300,
        "w": 480
      },
      {
        "url": "http://vodassets.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/unscaled/2013/07/15/LPA-Parental-guidance-LPA-to-LP4.jpg",
        "h": 600,
        "w": 960
      },
      {
        "url": "http://vodassets.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/unscaled/2012/11/29/Parental-Guidance-DI-DI-to-CW.jpg",
        "h": 720,
        "w": 1280
      }
    ]
    ],
```

and so on. I have to download all the items and cache the images within each asset.
Below is what I am trying to do in the beginning, but it seems to output me NULL. Can you help me, please ?

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents ("js/showcase.json");
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$allImages = $array['cardImages'];
var_dump($allImages);
?>
```

Comment: `var_dump($array)` and you will find your answer, it is easy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON file is an array, which means you need to fetch the item and then the key you need. In your case, you would use:

```
$allImages = $array[0]['cardImages'];
```

I hope I helped! -CM